# gettext ignores .mo file

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I'm trying to make get text working, and everything seems to be ok, but it wouldn't translate my text anyway. I read about 5 different posts on stackoverflow and another 5 on google - nothing helps. Here is what I have now:

1. I took php file from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)
2. I took po file example from [here](https://help.phrase.com/help/gettext-po-files)
3. I took gettext binaries from [here](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html)

These are the files which I end up using to make sure there can not be any error:

```
<?php
// Set language to English
putenv('LC_ALL=en');
putenv("LANGUAGE=en");
putenv("LC_MESSAGES=en");
putenv("LANG=en"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en');

// Specify location of translation tables
echo bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");
echo "<br>";

// Choose domain
echo textdomain("myPHPApp");
echo "<br>";

// Translation is looking for in ./locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo now

// Print a test message
echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");
echo "<br>";

// Or use the alias _() for gettext()
echo _("boolean_key");
echo "<br>";

echo _("key_with_description");
echo "<br>";


var_dump(_("key_with_description"));

echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
echo "<br>";
echo getenv('LC_ALL');
echo "<br>";
echo getenv('LANGUAGE');
echo "<br>";
echo getenv('LC_MESSAGES');
echo "<br>";
echo getenv('LANG');

echo phpInfo();

?>
```

locale\en\LC_MESSAGES\myPHPApp.po:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language: English\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Generator: PhraseApp (phraseapp.com)\n"

msgid "boolean_key"
msgstr "--- true"

msgid "empty_string_translation"
msgstr ""

# This is the amazing description for this key!
msgid "key_with_description"
msgstr "Check it out! This key has a description! (At least in some formats)"

msgid "key_with_line-break"
msgstr "This translations contains\na line-break."

msgid "nested.deeply.key"
msgstr "Wow, this key is nested even deeper."

msgid "nested.key"
msgstr "This key is nested inside a namespace."

msgid "null_translation"
msgstr ""

msgid "pluralized_key"
msgid_plural ""
msgstr[0] "Only one pluralization found."
msgstr[1] "Wow, you have %s pluralizations!"

msgid "sample_collection\n"
msgstr "---\n- first item\n- second item\n- third item\n"

msgid "simple_key"
msgstr "simple key, simple message, so simple.2"

#, fuzzy
msgid "unverified_key"
msgstr "I need verification, please verify me! (In some formats we also export this status)"


msgfmt en\LC_MESSAGES\myPHPApp.po --output-file=en\LC_MESSAGES\myPHPApp.mo
```

the output I get is:

```
D:\Work\locale
myPHPApp
Welcome to My PHP Application
boolean_key
key_with_description
string(20) "key_with_description" en
en
en
en
en
```

As you can see putenv, setlocale, bindtextdomain - all commands are working as expected.

I also check with phpInfo that gettext and mbstring extensions are detected. [image]

I also tried to restart apache.

I also tried to do the same, using 'de' instead of 'en'. Also I tried to use 'ru' and 'en-US'. All give me the same result. 'en_US' (with underscore) breaks even earlier, `setlocale` ignores it and the value of LC_ALL is left to be `LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C`.

I have english and russian installed on my system. [image]

What can be wrong here?

I'm using windows 7, PHP 5.6.40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/09/debugging-php-gettext/) has helped me. The solution was to set LANG=en in shell and then to run XAMPP from this exact shell.

> Finally, to get gettext working in XAMPP, you need to set the LANG
> attribute on the XAMPP shell before you fire up the XAMPP Control
> Panel every time you want to use XAMPP.
>
> The XAMPP shell is right inside the install folder, which means it
> should be at C:\xampp\xampp_shell.bat for most people. Run it
> (preferrably as an Administrator), and type the following:
>
> `set LANG=YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE`
>
> YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE needs to be replaced
> with the appropriate language code of your localisation. For example,
> if my localisation was for Simplified Chinese, it would look like
> this:
>
> `set LANG=zh_CN`
>
> Once done, use the following command to open the XAMPP
> Control Panel from the shell.
>
> `xampp-control`